# Are there operations that are not rotations?

Tags: group-theory

(I'm doing the first steps in group theory, so don't be harsh)

Since reflections in a plane are rotations around some 3D axis, the question is: if the number of dimensions is high enough, there are group operations in the plane that are not reducible to a combination of rotations on some high enough dimension?

For example, is there some arbitrary permutation of elements that cannot be reduced to (many) rotations on some n-dimensional space?

Comment: In my opinion it is not useful to think of, for example, a reflection in a 2D-plane as coming from a 3D-rotation. That hides the fact a reflection reverses handedness. Consider the following. Assume that your plane is a piece of paper. Color one side of the plane red and the other side green. If you try and perform that reflection by rotation the piece of paper in 3D, what happens is that the green and red sides trade places.

Comment: Anyway, what about parallel translations? You can't get those from a rotation. For a rotation preserves distances. In particular, the distance to the subspace of fixed points of the rotation (=its axis in 3D, something else in higher dimensions) stays the same. But repeatedly performing the same translation moves objects further and further out.

Comment: Also, there are other interesting group actions that don't preserve any idea of being "geometrically close". For example the mapping $\sigma$ that sends the number $a+b\sqrt2$ to $a-b\sqrt2$ for all rational numbers $a,b$. It is an interesting action because it preserves sums and products. It gives rise to an action of the cyclic group of order two because $\sigma\circ\sigma$ is the identity mapping. It maps $0$ to $0$. But it also maps the very small number $(1-\sqrt2)^{100}$ to a very large number $(1+\sqrt2)^{100}$.

Comment: Scaling: For $c>0$ let $S_c : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be given by $S_c(x,y)=(cx,cy).$ The set of such $S_c$ form a group acting on the plane. These operations can not be reduced to rotations.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen Physically, a parallel translation is a rotation around an infinitely distant axis, and complex conjugation is a reflection, which is also a rotation.

Comment: Who said anything about complex conjugation? All those numbers in the second example are real :-) I am not buying "rotation about an infinitely distant axis" without a definition of what you mean by *a rotation*. Otherwise anyone inclined to answer will be aiming at moving goalposts. While that is sometimes unavoidable, it becomes less appealing rather quickly. For me a rotation is a linear transformation from $\Bbb{R}^n$ to itself that preserves lengths and handedness (and as a linear transformation keeps the origin fixed). We can move the origin elsewhere to get a bit more elbow room.

Comment: The point of that number example was to show that a group need not act on all of $\Bbb{R}^n$. That action is undefined for some (=most) points on the line.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen I don't know enough to tell if that was moving the goalpost, but mapping a+bc to a-bc is a rotation around a. An on higher dimension is possible to invert handedness of a 3D object without changing internal lengths. I don't know if cyclic groups are equivalent to rotation in physical space. I just assumed it was.

Comment: No, it is not a rotation about $a$. If $a$ is a rational number, then $a+1$ is also rational, so it stays put whenever $a$ does. In that action $0\mapsto 0$, $1\mapsto 1$, $\sqrt2\mapsto -\sqrt2$, $1+\sqrt2\mapsto 1-\sqrt2$ and $17-12\sqrt2\approx0.029\mapsto 17+\sqrt{12}\approx33.97$.

Comment: But, it is not difficult to prove that if we have a finite cyclic group acting on all of $\Bbb{R}^n$ by *distance preserving transformations*, then the action is by rotations and/or reflections (or combinations thereof). It also follows that, by adding  extra dimensions (as in your 2D->3D example) we can achieve the same action on that subspace via rotations in $\Bbb{R}^{n+k}$.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen Does it means that any permutation in n dimension can be done with cyclic groups on higher dimension than n?

Comment: If by a permutation you mean the linear transformation that permutes the coordinates of all the points of $\Bbb{R}^n$ in the same way, then, yes, that applies. For example, with $n=5$, the linear transformation $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)\mapsto (x_2,x_3,x_1,x_5,x_4)$ is a rotation in the 3D-subspace $x_4=x_5=0$ by 120 degrees about the axis $(1,1,1)$ and a reflection w.r.t. the line $x_4=x_5$ in the 2D-subspace $x_1=x_2=x_3=0$. The latter you can replace by a rotation in 3D by adding a sixth coordinate as earlier.

Comment: So that permutation is a combination of two 3D-rotations in a 6D-space in that sense. My definition of a rotation includes such combos of rotations, underlying the need to have a precise definition :-)